# Where can I get free tarot cards images to print?

Tags: playing-cards, print-and-play

I am looking to download some set/s of tarot cards in order to print them. This needs to be from a free site. Grayscale cards are also acceptable. It would be great if the images are designed specially for printing on A4, as then I could print sheets and cut them up.

[Motivation of the question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/18331/3502)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as a product recommendation request - the same reasons apply here as for any game recommendations.

Comment: I agree the Q should be closed and would vote so if SO would let me. The provided answers are already awesome. Any further activity on the thread would be spam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most popular version in the English speaking world is the [Rider-Waite](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rider-Waite_tarot_deck) Tarot cards. These were published in the early 20th century.

This site has [The Pictorial Key to the Tarot](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tarot/pkt/index.htm) that contains B/W images of the Tarot cards (clicking those opens fair quality scans in color). The book and the images predate U.S. copyright laws.

These images here are the best [high quality scans](http://blog.goo.ne.jp/valet_de_coupe/e/cb9361a10db2c819ee498cf250f66813/?img=6cf5c9e139a36cb06a5cdd5a7505afde) I have found of these old images.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, you can download the images from the pictoral key to the tarot [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/tarot/pkt/index.htm).  I'm creating a deck, the Evolutionary Options Tarot which is being released into the creative commons.  That means copyright [free tarot card images](http://www.quickcardreading.com/free-tarot-card-images/)!  Have at it, and I'd appreciate any feedback.